# New lines not working in Javascript function when echoing in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, newline

This code below uses Javascript and PHP, but when it runs I want each echo to be on a separate line. I have tried using \n and <br>  and other methods but all of them dont have any effect on the text. Can anyone please help me?

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: '<?php echo "hello" . "\n" . "<br>" . "world"; ?>', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          {{ x.info.text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Edit: For some reason this snippet does not interpret the php.

Comment: I can't run your code -- it's full of undefined variables.  Please see this page -- [mcve] -- and give us an example that only has the problem you want us to address.

Comment: @TopologicalSort Ok, I have updated the question.

Comment: Your `<br>` should work in this case. You can do a small proof by writing your content manually in the html. Why (what's the effect) do you say they didn't work? Did they render as text? If so, it is probably your framework or engine escaping it to output a text form. Or a CSS thing? Hard to say without a minimal complete example. However, br tags inside a td do produce a newline :)

Comment: Try `<td ng-bind-html="x.info.text"></td>` BTW - The whole idea of angularjs is NOT to have PHP injected in the client side..........

Comment: @AlonEitan Doesn't matter. Where should I put that code?

Comment: Just replace `<td>{{ x.info.text }}</td>` with what I suggested `<td ng-bind-html="x.info.text"></td>` - I think it might work

Comment: @AlonEitan No, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Jez Can you at least see the details in the view? I mean - Does it show, just without the new lines?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, the text shows in the right place, but it is in one line.

Comment: Your first <td> tag around {{ x.name }} is not closed.

Comment: And what happen when you do `<td><pre>{{ x.info.text }}</pre></td>`?

Comment: @AlonEitan I have updated it again.

Comment: @Jez I have posted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the expression between `<pre></pre>` tags:

```
<td>
    <pre>{{ x.info.text }}</pre>
</td>
```

And then use `\n` as a line break (Forget the `<br>`).

Here's a working example. I removed the PHP tags and used plain text for the demo:

```
text: 'line 1\nline 2'
```

BTW - You can replace the `PRE` tags with a `white-space: pre;` css style.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: 'line 1\nline 2', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          <pre>{{ x.info.text }}</pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Didn't think about the pre. You're right. Otherwise represent text by array and nest ng-repeat in the <td> tag

Comment: I did upvoted your answer, because it provide an alternative to my solution. Nice chatting with you ;)

Comment: For some reason, the php works until i add the \n then it just shows the top blue one and does not show the boxes below it.

Comment: @Jez Try working with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): `text: <?php echo json_encode("hello\n" . $myVar); ?>` - **Note** that you should NOT wrap the what should be the property value with any quotes. This will explain what i'm talking about: `echo '{text: ' . json_encode('value with " and \' chars') . '}';`

Comment: @Jez Also, you can use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` - It should still work, and probably make it work again

Comment: @AlonEitan json_encode and PHP_EOL makes it do the same thing as \n.

Comment: @Jez Can you please post a new question about it (With full description about the issues when using the `\n` with PHP)? I'll be happy to take a look

Comment: @AlonEitan Ok, thanks, here is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167047/n-breaking-php-code-within-javascript

Comment: @Jez I see you've already got some answers, so i'm off to bed and i'll see if you got an answer when i'm back. If it's still not answered, then i'll post my suggestion (But I believe you'll get an answer from other users before). Bye for now

Comment: @AlonEitan I upvoted yours as well. Better for performance issue than a nested ng-repeat.

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for your help, now I want to make my css styles apply to the text in each box and I don't know what you mean by 'replace the PRE tags with a white-space: pre; css style'.

Answer (score 2):

The ng-bindings do not interpret html entities therefore you have to represent your echoes a such :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text:['<?php echo "hello" ?>','<?php echo  "world"; ?>'], show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}




<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }} </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          <p ng-repeat="txt in x.info.text">{{ txt }}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Your first `<td>` tag is not closed.

```
<tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
    <td> {{ x.name }} </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="x.info.show">
   <td>
      <p ng-repeat="txt in x.info.text">{{ txt }}</p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

By the way, It's bad practice to echo PHP in your Angular code.

Comment: I think that the browser will know how to handle this, by auto closing the tag when it gets to the `</tr>` wrapping the cell with the missing closing `</td>` tag

Comment: Then there is no reason a <br> inside à table data cell does not break line.

Comment: But the `<br>` tag is on the second cell, and it has a closing `</td>` tag

Comment: Yes, but still, some upper html code could break the rest. I've tested the table on chrome and the <br> tag does work even if the <td> before isn't closed. So you're right, but it's the only thing I can see that could prevent it from working.

Comment: The reason is that `ngBind` (which is the equivalent of `{{ expression }}`) doesn't work with html entities: [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) _The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the **text** content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression_ The OP is using PHP inside their controller - This is something i've never seen before... Making it pretty bad practice as a whole

Comment: Right I just figured out. What should be done is nested ng repeat and array representation of all different echoes