# \n breaking PHP code within Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

When I run this code on my PHP website, it works but when adding a \n after 'text:' as php to make a new line, the entries in the table below the blue title at the top stop showing. Below is a snippet of what the code is but it does not run php so it doesn't show the error.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: '<?php echo "This: \n breaks the code"; ?>', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          {{ x.info.text }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to escape the line-break twice.
One escape for JavaScript and one for php

Your current string generates this php:

```
<?php echo "This: 
breaks the code"; ?>
```

because the `\n` is evaluated by javascript into a linefeed character and this makes the php invalid.

You should use this string instead:

```
'<?php echo "This: \\n does not break the code"; ?>'
```

Answer (score 2):

\n will not show in HTML. You have to coding like this.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.environment_service_packages = 
[
  // &lt;br&gt; will be convert to <br>
  {name: 'obj1', info: {text: '<?php echo "This: &lt;br&gt; breaks the code"; ?>', show: true}}, 
  {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: false}},
];
}
```